# Is there a way to solve the undefined index error which occurs on a variable that has been declared and initialised

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I keep getting an error of undefined index on a variable that I have declared and initialized. I have already defined and initialized the variables so I do not understand why its coming out as undefined

I have already tried changing the syntax please see comments in code

```
<?php
include('upload-code.php'); 
//include('config.php');

       /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "promoapp");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$productName = "";

//$productName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['productName']);
$productName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,isset( $_REQUEST['productName']))? $_REQUEST['productName'];
?>
```

Comment: Which variable is that? are sure it's `$_REQUEST['productName']` instead of `$_REQUEST['productname']`?

Comment: The line. `$productName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,isset( $_REQUEST['productName']))? $_REQUEST['productName'];` is syntactically wrong and should throw a syntax error. Btw, look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping your variables.

Comment: Please show your upload-code.php here so we can see if anything goes wrong there!

Comment: You should add the full error message you get. You should also do some debugging. Start with `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productName =isset($_REQUEST['productName'])?mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_REQUEST['productName']): '';
```

I think you got confused with the ternary operator.

Above code checks if your variable isset and if not it will assign an empty value to the `$productName` variable.

If it exists it will execute the mysqli_real_escape_string with the 2 inputs the `$link` and the `$_REQUEST['productName']`